# How to implement a timer in Android Service

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to implement a function that is called every second and returns an integer value. This method also needs to be able to run in the background when the app is closed. To achieve this I use a Service

```
package de.ur.mi.android.tasks.eggtimer.service;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;


public class CountdownService extends IntentService{

    int time;


    public CountdownService() {
        super("CountdownService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        time = intent.getIntExtra("time", 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting timer for " + time + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startCountdown();

    }

    private void startCountdown()
    {

    }

}
```

the startCountdown method is supposed to be excuted every second and decrease the value of time by one until it reaches 0. After that time should be returned to the Activity that starts the service so I can update my TextView there.
I have absoluetly no clue what method to use and how to use it, Ive read about 10 StackOverflow posts by now but none of them helped.

Comment: I don't think you can run any method in the background every second. You can use WorkManager that guarantees to perform your task every 15 mint. But it looks like you need to perform some task when the counter becomes 0. So in that case calculates the time interval between input and output and use AlarmManager to perform the task on a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use foreground service if you need to do something when the app is closed.

in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

unfortunately i have only a kotlin sample but it should be clear enough:

Start service:

```
val svcIntent = Intent(App.instance, WorkerSvc::class.java)
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, svcIntent)
```

Service:

```
class WorkerSvc : Service() {


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }



    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        LogUtil.i("onStartCommand")
        startForeground(
            NotificationUtil.NOTIFICATION_ID,
            NotificationUtil.makeForeGroundNotification(getString(R.string.please_wait))
        )
        startCountdown()
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

To start the count down:

```
currentTimer =
                 object : CountDownTimer(time, 60 * 1000) {
                        override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
                            // do every second job
                        }

                        override fun onFinish() {
                            // do after finish job
                        }
                    }
currentTimer.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code it's work for you

```
private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
```

**onStop**

```
 protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    editor.apply();
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

**onStart**

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    updateCountDownText();
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateCountDownText();
        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

also just lookout [this](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/countdowntimer/part-3-run-in-background)